# Code coverage fine, but won't upload to production

Tags: apex, unit-test

I receive the following error message when trying to upload my code to production

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Service Record Type: this ID value
>   isn't valid for the user: 0128E0000004m8bQAA: [RecordTypeId]  Stack
>   Trace:
>   Class.TEST_OpOwnerConvertedServiceNotif.TEST_OpOwnerConvertedServiceNotif:
>   line 16, column 1

Below is my test class, what do I need to change, for this to upload to production?

```
@istest private class TEST_OpOwnerConvertedServiceNotif 
{
static testMethod void TEST_OpOwnerConvertedServiceNotif ()
{
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
    insert acc;

    ID pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

   RecordType RecType = [Select Name, Id From RecordType
              where sObjectType='Product2' and DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Service'];

    User U = [Select Id FROM User WHERE Email = 'glenn.daly@jisc.ac.uk'];


    Product2 prd1 = new Product2 (Name = 'Test Product Entry 1', Description = 'Test Product Entry 1',
                                  productCode = 'ABC', isActive = false,
                                  RecordTypeId = RecType.id,
                                  R_D_Service_Owner__c = u.Id,
                                  Convert_to_Service_Catalogue_Initiated__c = TRUE,
                                  Convert_to_Service_Catalogue_Emailed__c = FALSE);
                                    insert prd1;
    PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry
        (Product2ID=prd1.id, Pricebook2ID = pricebookId,UnitPrice=0, isActive=true);
            insert pbe1;

    Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity (Name='Opp1', StageName='Proposal Accepted', CloseDate=Date.today(),
                                        Pricebook2Id = pbe1.Pricebook2Id, AccountId = acc.id);
                                        insert opp1;

    OpportunityLineItem lineItem1 = new OpportunityLineItem
        (OpportunityID = opp1.id, PriceBookEntryID = pbe1.id, quantity=1, totalprice=0);
    insert lineItem1;

    Test.startTest();
      OpOwnerConvertedServiceNotif sobj = new OpOwnerConvertedServiceNotif();
 system.schedule('Scheduable_Class', '0 0 23 * * ?', sobj);

    Test.stopTest();


}
}
```

Comment: You have a hard coded Id. SF Ids will not sync from org to org. Query for R_D_Service_Owner__c like you did for the RecordType.Id.

Comment: I see only one problem for now -- that is hardcoded id for R_D_Service_Owner__c  -- 005w0000004x3RiAAI. It would be better to generate user in test method, and use it's id to ensure that it is always available

Comment: @JesseMilburn i've updated my code, and still have the same problem when trying to upload to production

Answer (score 3):

This error is telling you that the specified user profile doesn't have access to the record type you're trying to use (the 'Unavailable_R_D_Service' record type on 'Product2'). You can just go in to Setup, add the record type to the System Administrator profile, and then re-run your change set deployment.

Comment: I have gone into production, ensured sys admin has access to 'Unavailable_R_D_Service' record type on 'Product2' yet I stil have the same issue? I've also updated my code to take into account what Jesse said